# How to remove the extension file name when using button function in Data Table?

Tags: r, shiny

I've wanted to remove the csv extension when downloading the file using the Data Table button download. Whenever i pressed the pdf button, it will named the download file as **nameofthefile.csv.pdf** . I do wanted to get only the name of the file only. Is there anyway on how i need to fix in my code to fix this?

```
#display the reactive stats datatable
  output$statsDataframe <- renderDataTable({
    statsDF_reactive$df()
  }, extensions = 'Buttons',  options = list(scrollX = TRUE, 
                                             dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                             buttons = list(
                                               list(extend = 'copy', title = input$file$name), 
                                               list(extend = 'csv', title = input$file$name), 
                                               list(extend = 'excel', title = input$file$name), 
                                               list(extend = 'pdf', title = input$file$name), 
                                               list(extend = 'print', title = input$file$name) 
                                             )))
```

statsDF_reactive$df() is my dataset after go through data transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `tools::file_path_sans_ext(input$file$name)` or `sub('\\.csv$', '', input$file$name)` to remove the extension from filename.

Comment: Thanks it is working. Im using the sub('\\.csv$', '', input$file$name) as it is easier to intergrate into my codes.

Comment: I just want to ask, is it working if i did sub('\\.$', '', input$file$name) to remove any extension after "."

Comment: You would need to use `sub('\\..*', '', input$file$name)` to remove everything after `.`. This also means that your filename cannot have `.` in them. You can use `tools::file_path_sans_ext` which will handle such cases and also work for filenames with all extensions.